# SQLStorage Count(*) weird behaviour

Tags: sql, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 beta.4 SQLStorage, trying to count the occurrence of a value appearing in the column.

```
this.storage.query('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbstorage WHERE value = ?',[variable])
```

neither

```
this.storage.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbstorage WHERE value = ?',[variable])
```

works

the following codes works fine for samsung android phone(lolipop), while it doesn't run for iOS or another android phone(kitkat).

Insert , Select, Create Table statements work fine for all phones tested.

Is there any workaround for this? Or do I have to use another simpler query statement?

Comment: What do you mean with "weird behaviour", "doesn't run"? Do you get an exception, if so: what is the exception?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hi,there is no exception message printed in my web console.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The query does not return me any results, skipping the whole function,while other query statements works fine

Comment: it won't run if you does not have a columns called '1'. Try remove arguments in COUNT function and add "*"

Comment: @morels Count(*) does not work either

Comment: @Gene so try `SELECT *` and try remove variable input  explicating it in the string

Comment: I have no knowledge about ionic, but I would suggest to use column alias, like `select count(*) as cnt from...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I'm using this workaround unless someone has a better answer to this.

Instead of using 'Count' , I use Select statement and count the row length returned.

```
this.storage.query('SELECT value FROM dbstorage WHERE value= ?',[variable])
```

and getting the rows.length as the count

```
results.res.rows.length
```